# "Let guests invite friends" set to true - Facebook API (PHP SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

We are developing a Facebook application and can't find a way to either create an event that has the property "Let guests invite friends" set to true (or edit the event to set this property to true) or automatically make all invited friends administrators of that event. We need this, so that those friends can, through our application, invite other friends to the event.

We are using PHP SDK for Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invite users to an event by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID.

You can invite multiple users by issuing an HTTP POST to 
/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3.

Both of these require the create_event permission and return true if the invite is successful.

Full documentation in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/